# Why is this extremely simple code not working?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, loop

I have a problem with a for loop, and `Serial.print("Its Working")` does not appear. Seems simple, I've done it before, now for whatever reason, its not working anymore

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  for (int x = 0; x > 10; x++) {

    Serial.println("Its Working");
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x > 10; x++) {
```

That can be rewritten, in pseudo code, as:

- X is zero
- While X is greater than 10:

  - Increment X

You see the problem? X is zero. It's not greater than 10, so it never increments.

I *assume* you actually wanted:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
```

Also be aware that your `for` loop will be run over and over again, so you will never see it finish.  You should add

```cpp
Serial.println("Loop done");
```

at the end so you know it's finished.

Comment: Essentially, the for loop never starts as the first time it checks the condition, its already false, right?

Comment: @Coder9390 That is correct.

Comment: @Coder9390: You can see that for yourself by single-stepping your code with a debugger.  You'll see execution skip over the loop without ever entering the loop body.  That's your hint that you accidentally wrote a loop condition that's false on the first check.  Remember that a for loop is basically the same as `part1;`  / `while(part2){ ...; part3; }`, so like a while loop, the condition is checked before entering the loop for the first time.

Comment: @Coder9390:   Using a debugger is essential for low-level stuff where alternatives like sprinkling debug-print statements in your code aren't easy, or to help catch brain-farts where something you're assuming you got right was actually the problem.